# CString from NSData

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write a simple html parser in Swift. I imported libxml via a bridge header. But now I have the problem by getting the xml file into a `CString`. The method `htmlReadMemory` needs a CString as first parameter. I loaded the xml file into NSData. Passing `data.bytes` doesn't work. I'm getting the error

`Could not find an overload for '__conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments.`

In an obj-c code example, this way works. Why not in Swift? Any ideas, how I can bring the NSData to an CString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to convert it to `NSString` first, then you can use the `cString()` function:

```
   let xmlData = NSData()
   let cocoaString = NSString(data: xmlData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

   let cString = cocoaString.cString()
```

Comment: Thanks. Damn, I nearly had this solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work with `string.bridgeToObjectiveC().UTF8String`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer, I want to convert NSData ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use...

`let cString = string.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`