# Create CString from NSData

Tags: swift, nsdata

I have a C API that takes a pointer to arbitrary binary data with function signatures like the following:

```
void receiveData(const char *data, size_t length);
```

The bridging header imports this into Swift with the following definition:

```
func receiveData(data: CString, length: UInt)
```

I feel I'm missing something basic, but I can't seem to work out how to get a `CString` from arbitrary `NSData` - the only options seem to be conversion from `NSString` or as a string literal. How do I create the `CString`?

It would make more sense to be able to pass through a `CConstPointer<CChar>`, but the compiler isn't having a bar of it - is there some way to modify the Swift signature generated by the bridging header?

**Edit:** CString was removed in Xcode 6 Beta 4. From the release notes:

> The CString type has been removed. Values of type const char * are now
>   imported as ConstUnsafePointer instead of CString. C macros that
>   expand to string literals are imported as String.

Comment: This might be a dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147825/cstring-from-nsdata

Comment: @hotpaw2: no, this is about creating a CString from binary data, not encoded string data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C string is null-terminated. Arbitrary binary data doesn't need to be null terminated. I think the problem is that the bridging mechanism sees a `char *` and thinks "C string". Perhaps if you changed it to `void *`, you will get a more appropriate type in Swift.

Comment: That's definitely the problem, but it seems to be a fairly hefty assumption that the bridging header is making - a char * isn't necessarily a null terminated string. I'll change the header for now and give you the tick if no-one comes up with a better solution.